# When using http.createServer with clusters, why is callback provided to http.createServer being called more than once?

Tags: node.js

I was trying to understand how http requests are served by workers of a cluster. I started with the code at http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html and added some logging around it.

I put the following code in server.js and executed the file with:
NODE_DEBUG=cluster node server.js

```
var cluster = require('cluster');
var http = require('http');
var numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;
if (cluster.isMaster) {
    console.log('number of CPUs: ' + numCPUs);

    // Fork workers.
    for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
        console.log('forking worker ' + i);
        cluster.fork();
    }

    cluster.on('exit', function(worker, code, signal) {
        console.log('worker ' + worker.process.pid + ' died');
    });

} else {
    console.log('worker spawned: ' + cluster.worker.process.pid);

    var someVar = {'b': 1};
    // Workers can share any TCP connection
    // In this case its a HTTP server
    http.createServer(function(req, res) {
        console.log('someVar.b current value: ' + someVar.b + ". someVar.b will be incremented");
        someVar.b = someVar.b + 1;
        console.log('Request being processed by worker: ' + cluster.worker.process.pid);
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.end("hello world\n");
        console.log('response ended by worker: ' + cluster.worker.process.pid);
    }).listen(8000);
}
```

I then went to localhost:8000 once, and lo and behold, "hello world" was the response as I expected. What I didn't expect is some log statements being printed twice:

```
number of CPUs: 2
forking worker 0
forking worker 1
535,Master Worker 536 online
535,Master Worker 537 online
worker spawned: 536
worker spawned: 537
someVar.b current value: 1. someVar.b will be incremented
Request being processed by worker: 536
response ended by worker: 536
someVar.b current value: 2. someVar.b will be incremented
Request being processed by worker: 536
response ended by worker: 536
```

Specifically, I expected that for one request to my server, the following lines would only be printed once:

```
someVar.b current value: X. someVar.b will be incremented
Request being processed by worker: XXX
response ended by worker: XXX
```

Instead my functions are getting executed twice *by the same worker*. Could someone please shed some light on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check `req.url`? I bet one of the two requests is for `/favicon.ico`.